# Chaining vagrant files

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I already have a project file `projectpath/Vagrantfile` and a
personal/global `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`

I use the global Vagrantfile to setup certain `synced_folder`s to access my various dotfiles within the VM.  These are definitely personal configs that should not be mixed with the project file which is shared with team members.

I am looking to be able to add certain personal per-project config.  Specifically i'm adding additional forwarded ports just for my personal needs, but I don't want to do it for all of my VMs.

I was hoping to have a `projectpath/my_vagrantfile.rb` or anything like that dropped in that same directory (and would be in my global git-ignore file)

I suspect I can execute a conditional `load` from within the global Vagrantfile but was wondering if there is a cleaner, more vagrant-y way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/) on LOAD ORDER AND MERGING:

> An important concept to understand is how Vagrant loads Vagrantfiles.
>   Vagrant actually loads a series of Vagrantfiles, merging the settings
>   as it goes. This allows Vagrantfiles of varying level of specificity
>   to override prior settings. Vagrantfiles are loaded in the order shown
>   below. Note that if a Vagrantfile is not found at any step, Vagrant
>   continues with the next step.
>
> 1. Vagrantfile packaged with the box that is to be used for a given machine.
> 2. Vagrantfile in your Vagrant home directory (defaults to ~/.vagrant.d). This lets you specify some defaults for your system
>      user.
> 3. Vagrantfile from the project directory. This is the Vagrantfile that you'll be modifying most of the time.
> 4. Multi-machine overrides if any.
> 5. Provider-specific overrides, if any.

If you share the same box with your project team members, 1. will not really be an option neither.

One solution would be to create this `projectpath/my_vagrantfile.rb` (assuming projectpath/ is the folder of your project where you have Vagrantfile and .vagrant/ directory with VM information).

You then add the following in your *global* Vagrantfile

```
if File.file?("#{Dir.pwd}/my_vagrantfile.rb")
  eval File.read("#{Dir.pwd}/my_vagrantfile.rb")
end
```

One drawback is that it would work only if you run `vagrant` from your `projectpath` directory as `Dir.pwd` will reference this folder. (i.e. 
*Returns the path to the current working directory of this process as a string.*)
If you run `vagrant up` specifying the VM Id or calling from a subfolder of projectpath it would not be able to reference the custom my_vagrantfile.rb

Comment: It's not clear where are you suggesting that this code-block should live.  Ideally it would be in the global Vagrantfile (#2 in the list you quoted)

Comment: okay no, I really meant to create the new file in your project directory (what you call projectpath, note it could live in projectpath/.vagrant/ so its part of your global ignored I guess) and add that in your project (local to projectpath) Vagrantfile, as you have a condition on the existence of the custom Vagrantfile it will not make any harm to the other team members

Comment: ok trying to make it more clear and change `__FILE__` with `Dir.pwd`

Comment: ok rereading the last sentence, right it does not provide more but then I dont think its possible as mentioned by the doc and highlighted in the first part of the answer

Comment: yes, the __FILE__ had me suspicious ...   accepting answer though I'm using `load` rather than `eval  File.read` can you explain why not use `load`?

Comment: Reading some of the vagrant code it looked like one could monkey patch an additional path which didn't seem that clean

Comment: `The existence of this function is primarily a convenience. There is nothing stopping you from instantiating your own {Vagrantfile}`  https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/be29915bed75b6cf97301051ab4eef195a200f71/lib/vagrant/environment.rb#L730